# Split home screen, vertically on desktop then horizontally on mobile

Tags: bulma

I have a home page with 2 main entries, I split it in 2 columns of `hero`. That's good for desktop display. On mobile the columns are split to 2 rows, because of responsiveness, but scrolling is not an option here, as users do not notice the second entry and miss it. A solution would be to split the screen in 2 rows. Is that possible with `hero`, to set half height for mobile only?